# In-memory option in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, in-memory-database, in-memory

I am using Entity Framework to manage my SQL Server. Is there an option to make it faster using in-memory service with Entity Framework?

I found only in-memory support for testing in Entity Framework, and it doesn't seem to be what im looking for.

Comment: You are right, it should not be used in this context. What are you trying to achieve? What kind of oparations are too slow in your database?

Comment: SQL Server 2014 and newer have a feature called "Hekathon" which is basically an "in-memory" database service: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/hekaton-in-1000-words/ and EF Core 1.0 has an "in-memory" option - not sure if that's good for production, or just for testing, though